# Why is my texture distorted after using Smart UV unwrap?

Tags: texturing, uv

When I use smart uv unwrap the texture from my model will be distorted. Do you have an idea what it could be?

Sorry if my English isn't realy good.

Comment: hello, please share some pictures, details, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Either the above or make sure to hit ctrl+a and set all transforms. I have learned that is a lot of my issues with almost anything including UV mapping.